# How to make \const{\length{\list}} work without modifying the implementation of \const?

Tags: macros

`\const` does not work for the current definition. It is defined to easily declared constants in both TeX and PostScript scopes. For example, if I want to define a const `Speed` of a value `300000000`, I can declare it with a single call `\const{Speed}{300000000}` which is known in both PS and TeX scopes. Another example, if I want to create a const `NumberOfElements` in PS and TeX scopes, I can call `\const{NumberOfElements}{\length{\list}}` where `\length` (defined as shown in the MWE) and `\def\list{a,b,c}`.

The problem is I have no knowledge **to make `\const{\length{\list}}` work while keeping `\const` works as the original intent**. Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add,fp}

% user defined data
\def\listX{1,2,3,4,5,6}
\def\listY{1,2,3}

% to determine the number of elements in a list
\newcounter{x}
\def\length#1{\setcounter{x}{0}\psforeach{\i}{#1}{\stepcounter{x}}\thex}


% to create constants in both TeX and PS scopes
\def\const#1#2{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \pstVerb{/#1 \csname#1\endcsname\space def}%
}



\const{Nx}{\length{\listX}}
\const{Ny}{\length{\listY}}
\const{CellW}{1}
\const{CellH}{2}


\const{CanvasWidth}{Nx*CellW}
\const{CanvasHeight}{Ny*CellH}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](\CanvasWidth,\CanvasHeight)
    % use other PS constants here
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Bonus question: Is there a smarter way to know the number of elements in a list?

Comment: Could you try to come up with a more descriptive title to your question, one that is more specific? The current title could hopefully apply to any question we have here -- I don't think people ask questions that they can easily answer themselves.

Comment: This is a better title, but I don't think the _works_ is grammatically correct. Howsabout omitting the word?

Comment: Great title....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's see the matter in general, though a deep discussion would require many pages of a book.

You are concerned with definitions of commands, not only with nesting macro calls. The "working" definition

```
\def\const#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}
```

with the call

```
\const{Count}{\length{\list}}
```

is equivalent to

```
\def\Count{\length{\list}}
```

If you have also `\def\list{1,2,3}`, then

```
\const{Count}{\length{\list}}\Count
```

would print 3. However, if you say

```
\def\list{1,2,3}
\const{Count}{\length{\list}}
\Count

\def\list{a,b,c,d}
\Count
```

you'd get

> 3
>   4

Why? Because the macro `\Count` is defined in terms of `\list`, which will then use the current meaning of `\list`, not the one at definition time: `\list` is just a pointer to a token list (the current replacement text).

Your problem is to assign as the meaning `\Count` the *current* length of `\list`, independently from possible subsequent redefinitions. And you want it as a plain number, because you must pass it to `\pstVerb` as the replacement text of a PostScript token.

The way to cope with this is to perform the computations, store the numeric result in a temporary control sequence and then using `\edef`.

Here's a way:

```
\makeatletter
\newcount\const@count
\def\length#1{%
  \const@count=\z@
  \@for\next:=#1\do{\advance\const@count\@ne}%
  \edef\@tempa{\number\const@count}%
}
\def\const#1#2{%
  #2%
  \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\@tempa
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\pstVerb{/#1 \@tempa\space def}}\x
}
\makeatother
```

Call this as

```
\const{Count}{\length{\list}}
```

The important thing is to perform the computation *before* defining `\Count` and doing `\pstVerb`.

This is analogous to what you're doing elsewhere with `\FPeval`.

First of all `\length{\list}` is computed and the result is stored in `\@tempa` with `\edef`, so that the actual number is the replacement text. Then `\let` will make `\Count` have the current meaning of `\@tempa` and then the `\pstVerb` is emitted, in an indirect way, to avoid any reference to `\@tempa` in the replacement text, thanks to `\edef` again.

---

Let' try to generalize this; I suggest a three argument macro:

```
\makeatletter
\def\const#1#2#3{% #1=name, #2=method, #3=data
   #2{#1}{#3}%
   \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
     \noexpand\pstVerb{/#1 \csname#1\endcsname\space def}}\x
}
\newcount\const@count
\def\length#1#2{%
  \const@count=\z@
  \@for\next:=#2\do{\advance\const@count\@ne}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{\number\const@count}%
}
\makeatother
```

Now `\const{Count}{\length}{\list}` or `\const{ABC}{\FPeval}{2*3}` will work.

If `\FPeval` is the default method, you can simplify the syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,fp}

% user defined data
\def\list{1,2,3,4,5,6}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\const[3][\FPeval]{% #1=method, #2=name, #3=data
   \expandafter#1\csname#2\endcsname{#3}%
   \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
     \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}\x
}
\newcount\const@count
\def\length#1#2{%
  \const@count=\z@
  \@for\next:=#2\do{\advance\const@count\@ne}%
  \edef#1{\number\const@count}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\const[\length]{Count}{\list}
\Count

\const{ABC}{2*2}
\ABC
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is simplest if you work purely by expansion, then the behaviour of the TeX and PS constructs are more similar. I changed the syntax slightly using `\` in the product expression to save parsing the tokens.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add,fp}

% user defined data
\def\listX{1,2,3,4,5,6}
\def\listY{1,2,3}

% to determine the number of elements in a list
\makeatletter

\long\def\length#1{%
\expandafter\xlength\expandafter0#1,\relax,}

\long\def\xlength#1#2,{%
\ifx\relax#2%
\the\numexpr#1\relax
\expandafter\@gobblefour
\fi
\expandafter\xlength\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}}
\makeatother

% to create constants in both TeX and PS scopes
\def\const#1#2{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{\the\numexpr#2\relax}%
    \pstVerb{/#1 \csname#1\endcsname\space def}%
}



\const{Nx}{\length{\listX}}
\const{Ny}{\length{\listY}}
\const{CellW}{1}
\const{CellH}{2}


\const{CanvasWidth}{\Nx*\CellW}
\const{CanvasHeight}{\Ny*\CellH}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](\CanvasWidth,\CanvasHeight)
    % use other PS constants here
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```